# istio oauth filter error with secrets creation - updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_8443: paths must refer to an existing path in the system does not exist

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I'm running istio on kubernetes (container istio/proxyv2:1.13.2) and currently use oauth2-proxy pod to authenticate with keycloak. I have a requirement to replace oauth2-proxy with an istio oauth filter, and I'm attempting to deploy the oauth filter to the istio ingressgateway by following [this blog](https://szczeles.github.io/OAuth2-based-authentication-on-Istio-powered-Kubernetes-clusters/). When deploying the YAML below I get see the following error in istiod logs:

`2022-05-12T16:59:58.080449Z     warn    ads     ADS:LDS: ACK ERROR istio-ingressgateway-7fd568fc99-fvvcc.istio-system-150 Internal:Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_8443: paths must refer to an existing path in the system: '/etc/istio/config/token-secret.yaml' does not exist`

It looks to me that there is an issue loading the secret YAML files into the ingressgateway pod using SDS - but I could be wrong on this as I dont fully understand how this secret loading should be working in this example. I cant find documentation on this in the latest istio versions so as such I'm  struggling. Older docs talk about an sds container running in the istiogateway pod but this doesn't seem to be relevant in the more recent istio versions.

Can anyone help, or explain how the secrets get loaded into ingressgateway in the example that I'm following, and what the issue might be/how to diagnose ? Any help gratefully received.

The code is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: oauth2-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: CLUSTER
    match:
      cluster:
        service: oauth
    patch:
      operation: ADD
      value:
        name: oauth
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        connect_timeout: 10s
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        transport_socket:
          name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
            sni: keycloak.mydomain.com
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: oauth
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: keycloak.mydomain.com
                    port_value: 443
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.filters.http.oauth2
       typed_config:
         "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.oauth2.v3.OAuth2
         config:
          token_endpoint:
            cluster: oauth
            uri: https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
            timeout: 3s
          authorization_endpoint: https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
          redirect_uri: "https://%REQ(:authority)%/callback"
          redirect_path_matcher:
            path:
              exact: /callback
          signout_path:
            path:
              exact: /signout
          credentials:
            client_id: myclient
            token_secret:
              name: token
              sds_config:
                path: "/etc/istio/config/token-secret.yaml"
            hmac_secret:
              name: hmac
              sds_config:
                path: "/etc/istio/config/hmac-secret.yaml"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-oauth2
  namespace: istio-system
data:
  token-secret.yaml: |-
    resources:
      - "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.Secret"
        name: token
        generic_secret:
          secret:
            inline_string: "myclientsecrettext"
  hmac-secret.yaml: |-
    resources:
      - "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.Secret"
        name: hmac
        generic_secret:
          secret:
            # generated using `head -c 32 /dev/urandom | base64`
            inline_bytes: "XYJ7ibKwXwmRrO/yL/37ZV+T3Q/WB+xfhmVlio+wmc0="
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: jwt-authentication
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/myrealm"
      jwksUri: "https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
      forwardOriginalToken: true
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: known-user
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  rules:
  - when:
    - key: request.headers[Authorization]
      notValues:
      - 'Bearer*'
  - when:
    - key: request.auth.audiences
      values:
        - 'oauth'
    - key: request.auth.presenter
      values:
```